How to do this expo project the right way
Im new to expo. Im trying to make a webview app. It should be able to check if there's an internet connection before loading URl. And if there's none, it will show a simple message. What i have now is working,but i think this is not the right way to do it. I modified an expo project which has tabs in it. I dont need the tabs, just need one webview. There's a +not-found.tsx file but dont know how to use it
[app/_layout.tsx]
import { DarkTheme, DefaultTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import { Stack } from 'expo-router';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import 'react-native-reanimated';
import { useColorScheme } from '@/hooks/useColorScheme';

import { Platform , StyleSheet, View, StatusBar, Text } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import {useNetInfo, addEventListener} from "@react-native-community/netinfo";
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  SafeAreaProvider,
  SafeAreaInsetsContext,
  useSafeAreaInsets,
} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

// Prevent the splash screen from auto-hiding before asset loading is complete.
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function RootLayout() {
    const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
    const [loaded] = useFonts({
    SpaceMono: require('../assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),
    });
    const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
    const netInfo = useNetInfo();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (loaded) {
          SplashScreen.hideAsync();
        }
    }, [loaded]);

    if (!loaded) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
    <>
        {!netInfo.isConnected ? (

                <WebView
                    source={{ html: '<html><head><style>body,html{min-height:100%;}</style></head><body><div class="middle">No connection</div></body></html>' }}
                    style={{ flex: 1}}
                    containerStyle={{flex: 1, paddingTop: insets.top }} //useSafeAreaInsets .insets
                    applicationNameForUserAgent={'Expo/1.0'}
                    scalesPageToFit={true}
                    javaScriptEnabled={true}
                    domStorageEnabled={true}
                    startInLoadingState={true}
                    scalesPageToFit={true}
                    scrollEnabled={true}
                />

            ): (

                <WebView
                    ref={(ref) => (this.WebView = ref)}
                    source={{ uri: 'https://webviewapp.tld/home' }}
                    style={{ flex: 1}}
                    containerStyle={{flex: 1, paddingTop: insets.top }} //useSafeAreaInsets .insets
                    applicationNameForUserAgent={'Expo/1.0'}
                    scalesPageToFit={true}
                    javaScriptEnabled={true}
                    domStorageEnabled={true}
                    startInLoadingState={true}
                    scalesPageToFit={true}
                    scrollEnabled={true}
                />
            )
            }




        <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" backgroundColor="#FAFAF9" />

    </>
    );
}


